# Is it meaningful and possible to install two thermostat on one heating boiler and separate the heat

Tags: water-heater

I asked this because the area of first floor is huge so that the front part is not warm enough. Three relevant question to be asked here.

1)Is it meaningful and possible to install two thermostat on one heating boiler and separate the heating zone into two on the first floor using the same boiler simultaneously?(By saying separated into two heating zone, I meant to say to separate the heating cycle of first floor into two on the same boiler)

2)when I do this, do I need to installed another pressure gauge?

3)What is the advantage and disadvantage when comparing with other plan?

It is a 20 feet times 68 feet house that had water heating system and a type of baseboard that using finned tube as shown as below, basement and second floor use separate boiler or water heat. Much appreciated if you enlighten me. If it is possible, please also cite website link.

[image]

Comment: If I understand your question, the thermostat controls the heat generation, not the subsequent distribution.  You can't create two zones from one by adding thermostats.  The baseboard registers typically have adjustable vanes that allow you to control how much heat escapes from the register.  Use that to reduce the heat in the well-heated area and increase it in the poorly heated area.  Then adjust the thermostat to the best compromise.  You can also add electric space heaters in the coldest rooms.

Comment: @fixer1234 -- you bigtime underestimate the zonability of hydronic systems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is what zone valves are for

What you want isn't a standard thermostat that turns the boiler on and off -- what you actually want is to run the circulator and boiler on demand (i.e. they run if any zone is demanding heat) and then to use thermostatically controlled *zone valves* to turn on and off waterflow to each zone, whether it be a length of fin-tube, a radiator or three, a radiant floor in some room, or an air handler.  With this, you can run all *three* floors off of the same boiler even -- large buildings routinely are heated using independently zoned hydronic air handlers in each room all run off a single large boiler plant.

(As a sidenote, there are multi-circulator zoning techniques, but a circulator is bigger, heavier, more power-hungry, and more likely to break than a zone valve :)

Comment: I've only been exposed to simple residential systems without thermostatically-controlled zone valves (and the question is about an area of one floor).  If the setup doesn't contain this hardware, what's involved in modifying a system to subdivide zones if needed and upgrade the hardware?

Comment: @fixer1234 -- it's a fair bit of plumbing to install the valves, and a bit of controls work as well to get the zone thermostats hooked up and redo the boiler/circulator control

Comment: How difficult it is to create separate circuits will depend a lot on the layout of your plumbing and how your house is constructed. It could be a small job or a very big one. The other stuff - adding valves, rewiring thermostats and possibly changing your timer shouldn't be too big a deal after that.

Comment: +1 :) Sorry if this make it annoying.  1) If I want to install two thermostat in addition to what you say, will it be more convenient to control the heat as the boiler is install in the basement? 2) Will it beneficial in any aspect (economically or functionally) to reconnect and separate the piping into two group (front and back) instead just to install the zone valve?

Comment: @Victor -- 1) the zone valves often require a thermostat to control them (although you can get a *thermostatic radiator valve* that's an all-in-one unit). 2) this depends on your existing piping setup, talk with someone on-site who knows hydronics like the back of their hand for details

Comment: much appreciate for your help - to ThreePhaseEel

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly answer your questions we need to know exactly what the layout of your system is. My first question would be; what type of system do you have? Is it a series loop--The heating loop starts at the boiler connects to one piece of finned tubing which in turn connects to each room in a straight run with no other connections except the next set of fins. This tube runs all the way around to each room and back to the boiler. If this is the case, the easiest connection type would be to split the runs into 2. Take the 2 copper runs (the supply and return), tee them together at the boilers supply, now go to the exact center of the run, at the end of the house and add add a tee and run a new return pipe one size larger than the 2 supplies back to the boiler which becomes the new return. Now you have 2 supplies each heating 1/2 the floor and a common return. There are other configurations for a heating system this is just one example. To get a better understanding of your system GOOGLE "series loop heating systems"  for examples of the different type systems that could be installed. With out knowing the type of system you have, no one can give specific answers to your question.

Comment: +1 You had a brilliant mind to guess this correctly, thanks for your suggestion.